# Multi-line batch command created in PHP does not recognize my declared variable

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

My php class creates the following command:

```
INSERT INTO contacts (firstName, lastName) VALUES ('jon', 'snow') 
DECLARE @IDcontacts VARCHAR(200)
SET @IDcontacts = @@IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO emailAddresses (ownerId, emailAddress) VALUES (@IDcontacts, 'jon@thewall.com') 
INSERT INTO emailAddresses (ownerId, emailAddress) VALUES (@IDcontacts, 'jon@winterfell.com') 

INSERT INTO emailAddresses (ownerId, emailAddress) VALUES (@IDcontacts, 'thebastard@winterfell.com')
```

I create the connection, begin a transaction with, and execute the batch with `sqlsrv_query()`.

After executing the batch, `sqlsrv_errors()` gives me four errors: `[Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@IDcontacts".`

however, if I use exactly the same batch string in SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine and all four records are inserted with the correct identity value from the first insert.

I'm using SQL Server Express 2005, php version 5.4.3 and the most recent sqlsrv driver.  I haven't been able to find anything about this on technet or the ms forums, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY.

Comment: Thanks, but SCOPE_IDENTITY() and removing the semi colon give the same results.  Still works in the management server but returns the same errors when I run it in PHP.

Comment: @Beartums: My comment is just a comment and not an answer.  I would use a stored procedure to do these INSERTs.

Comment: @@IDENTITY is only valid for a specific connection and or transaction. Is the above statement in one command?

Comment: Yes.  There's a single sqlsrv_query() statement that send the entire string with all 6 t-sql statements in it.  I also tried SCOPE_IDENTITY() but it worked exactly the same way.

Comment: @Beartums, hmm... it will not help probably, but what if you type all comands as a single row (with no breaks) ? Or can it happen, that sql is trimmed somehow before passing to `sqlsrv_query()` ?

Comment: @i-one: thanks for the suggestion, but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, as described in a response to this question on the MSDN forums, the SQL is not executed as a batch even when submitted as a single string.  Each command is executed by `sp_executesql`, which makes every command run in a separate scope.

I suppose I could use a global temporary table to do the same thing, but instead chose to rewrite the PHP to handle each command separately, handling transactions, errors, and backreferences after each command is attempted.  I was hoping that wasn't true, but I am told it is.